# is INCRBY possible by using redis-om for record update atomicity?

Tags: node.js, redis, atomic

-Redis-om client does not have any "incrby" method to make atomicity of record Update.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Redis client
https://github.com/redis/redis-om-node#-connect-to-redis-with-a-client

```
import { Client } from 'redis-om';

const client = new Client();
await client.open('redis://localhost:6379');
const value = 1;
const aString = await client.execute(['INCRBY', 'key', value]);
```